Software rendering on Zhaoxin KX-6000 C-960 GPU
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 on Lenovo Kaitian using Zhaoxin CPU with C-960 iGPU.
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: KX-6000 C-960 GPU
     vendor: Zhaoxin
     physical id: 1
     bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
     version: 00
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
     configuration: latency=0
     resources: memory:c0300000-c037ffff memory:a0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000-dffff
*-graphics
     product: simpledrmdrmfb
     physical id: 1
     logical name: /dev/fb0
     capabilities: fb
     configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768

So I can see that the lshw identifies the GPU but is stuck in software rendering. It is my understanding that linux kernel had support for this GPU for a long time so I am unsure how to proceed here.
System details:
# System Details Report
---

## Report details
- **Date generated:**                              2024-08-21 15:05:50

## Hardware Information:
- **Hardware Model:**                              KaiTian KaiTian N80z G1d
- **Memory:**                                      16.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   ZHAOXIN KaiXian KX-U6780A@2.7GHz × 8
- **Graphics:**                                    Software Rendering
- **Disk Capacity:**                               512.1 GB

## Software Information:
- **Firmware Version:**                            W08KT40A
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               46
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.8.0-40-generic

Could Wayland be the issue?
Thank you for any help!

Well, it turns out only the CPU in KX6000 is supported in the kernel, iGPU is a different story. Zhaoxin provides a driver but unfortunately only for kernel 5.15...

Please click the checkmark beside your answer to mark it as accepted.
